# How do I modify the python code to check if the biscuit packet is empty before continuing the loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code is for selecting random biscuits from a family assorted pack or Arnott's. We are required to modify the code to check if the pack is empty before continuing the loop. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import random

biscuits = []

biscuits.extend(['Monte Carlo']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Shortbread Cream']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Delta Cream']*6)
biscuits.extend(['Orange Slice']*6)
biscuits.extend(['Kingston']*5)

print('\nASSORTED CREAMS\n')

print('There are ', len(biscuits), ' biscuits in the pack.')

print('\n', biscuits, '\n')

more = input('\nWould you like a biscuit (Y/N)... ')

while more != 'N':
    choice = random.randint(0,len(biscuits)-1)
    print('Your biscuit is : ', biscuits[choice])
    del biscuits[choice]
    more = input('\nWould you like a biscuit (Y/N)...')

print('\nThere are ', len(biscuits), ' biscuits left.')
print('\n', biscuits, '\n')
```

Comment: ```while more != 'N' and biscuits:```?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put the `input` code to `while loop`, and add biscuits-empty verification to while statement.You can try this:

```py
import random

biscuits = []

biscuits.extend(['Monte Carlo']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Shortbread Cream']*7)
biscuits.extend(['Delta Cream']*6)
biscuits.extend(['Orange Slice']*6)
biscuits.extend(['Kingston']*5)

print('\nASSORTED CREAMS\n')

print('There are ', len(biscuits), ' biscuits in the pack.')

print('\n', biscuits, '\n')

more = ''
while more != 'N' and biscuits:
    more = input('\nWould you like a biscuit (Y/N)...')
    choice = random.randint(0,len(biscuits)-1)
    print('Your biscuit is : ', biscuits[choice])
    del biscuits[choice]

print('\nThere are ', len(biscuits), ' biscuits left.')
print('\n', biscuits, '\n')
```